# Android updated system app is not granted new permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have an app that is installed into our custom ROM in `/system/app`

When I add a system permission, such as `android.permission.REBOOT`, and install an update to the system app, the updated app does not get the new permission added in the update.

When I add a non-system permission, such as `android.permission.INTERNET`, the app *does* see the new permission.

We are trying to understand if there is a way to get around this without OTA'ing the system app.

EDIT: here is how we are installing the package,

```
Class<?>[] installTypes = new Class[]{Uri.class, IPackageInstallObserver.class, int.class, String.class};
installMethod = pm.getClass().getMethod("installPackage", installTypes);
...
installMethod.invoke(pm, new Object[]{apkFile, observer, INSTALL_REPLACE_EXISTING, null});
```

Comment: How are you installing the update?

Comment: we are using reflection to call the `PackageManager.installPackage()` method.

Comment: please see the edit above for the code.

Comment: Have you incremented the versionCode in Manifest?

Comment: yes, version code was incremented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System apps cannot be granted new permissions through an upgrade. The reason, I assume, is that if you ever compromised a system app, you could upgrade it and add any permission you want, including all of the dangerous permissions that can only be granted to system apps.

If you want your system app to have a new permission, you need to perform a OTA, or otherwise get the new bits of the APK into `/system/app`.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this, either documentation or source? It would be a good addition to the answer to see where/how you found this information.

Comment: sorry, just empirical evidence. as i mentioned, it's also a bit of common sense that it works like this. of course i could be wrong and this could all be an artifact of something i haven't thought of.

Comment: I agree it's good common sense, I was mainly looking for something concrete to point to if/when someone asks the question in the future.